# Unset session array in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to `unset($_SESSION['cart']);` it is not work 1st time once item is added in cart and I am trying to remove cart. But it is work fine when I refresh the same page again.but session is already created and it is printed on screen.

Comment: Sounds like an issue of when you are unsetting the session? You need to unset it prior to printing the output. Hard to tell without seeing more code though :-)

Answer (score 1):

In codeigniter you have to unset the values of session by assigning null value to the session data like this(if you have multiple fields)

```
$unset_session = array('fields_that_session_contains'=>'');

$this->session->unset_userdata($unset_session);
```

you can also try this it will work

`$this->session->sess_destroy();`

i hope this will work for you

Comment: But I have multiple session array in my session .I need to destroy only one single session array

Comment: change your setting variable code with this `$this->session->set_userdata('session_name',array('session_store'=>$value));` this will help out, and my answer will be eligible to unset you session if you use this type of code

Answer (score 0):

The codeigniter way, you should have this in your controller BEFORE the view is loaded:

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('cart');
```

Answer (score 0):

I find unsettling session in array works better like

```
unset($_SESSION['cart']['some_item']);
```